# Error while creating a DB object from the IRB console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, database-migration, nomethoderror

While I was trying to create an object from the IRB console, I got an error that I couldn't quite understand. I have created a model already with the name `Subject`.

**Migration**:

```
class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :position
      t.boolean :visible

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Error**:

```
    subjects = Subject.new
    (irb):5:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Subject (NameError)
    Did you mean?  Object
            from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.3.5/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What you shared is a migration, it is used to create the table in the database to use the objects you need to create a model.

Comment: yes i've done that

Comment: Sorry didn't notice at first you are in `irb` that is `interactive ruby shell`, for rails you need to do `rails c` there you can create objects of your models.

Comment: Hi @BAVANMY, can you also please provide your model details. As @Abdul mentioned, it's more convenient to work from your `rails console` to create `objects` in your `DB`. That error occurs when your `ClassObject` (`Subject` in this case) isn't created properly in your tables. Possible problems: `typos`, `missing_migrations`, and more. I suggest you restart your console and try again. You can find more info here: <https://www.thoughtco.com/nameerror-uninitialized-2907928>